# Scroll bars with QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt

I've created two scroll areas in Qt Designer. Each of them has size [(31,48) 1141 x 161] and [(31, 310) 1141 x 101], respectively. Then I've created two widgets copy of TimeDiagram class, I've set them sizes that are bigger than sizes of the respective scroll areas. And then I've set the objects to the areas. Vertical and Horizontal scroll bars are enabled.

Constructor of the window:

```
GraphicScaleDialog::GraphicScaleDialog(OutputData *outputData, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::GraphicScaleDialog) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    data = outputData;

    commonSAGridSpacing = 120;
    commonSAScale = 15;
    resultsSAGridSpacing = 120;
    resultsSAScale = 15;

    ui->commonSAGridSpacing_line->setText(QString::number(commonSAGridSpacing));
    ui->commonSAScale_line->setText(QString::number(commonSAScale));
    ui->resultsSAGridSpacing_line->setText(QString::number(resultsSAGridSpacing));
    ui->resultsSAScale_line->setText(QString::number(resultsSAScale));

    commonArea = ui->commonScrollArea;
    commonArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
    commonArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
    resultsArea = ui->resultsScrollArea;
    resultsArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
    resultsArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);

    commonDiagramWidget = new TimeDiagram(20, this);
    commonDiagramWidget->setGeometry(31, 41, 2000, static_cast<int>(data->outputSettings.flowQuantity * commonDiagramWidget->rowHeight));
    resultsDiagramWidget = new TimeDiagram(100, this);
    resultsDiagramWidget->setGeometry(31, 114, 2000, 101);

    commonArea->setWidget(commonDiagramWidget);
    resultsArea->setWidget(resultsDiagramWidget);

    commonArea->show();
    resultsArea->show();
}
```

[image: Diagrams]

The problem is to create two grids with timeline axis.

Is it right that I need to use QPainter for this problem?

**UPD:**
May be problem in methods of TimeDiagram?

```
void TimeDiagram::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */) {
    QPainter  painter(this);
    draw(&painter);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------

void TimeDiagram::draw(QPainter *painter) {
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter ::NonCosmeticDefaultPen, true);
    QPen* pen = new QPen();
    pen->setWidth(1);

    pen->setColor(Qt::black);
    painter->setPen(*pen);
    for (int i = static_cast<int>(rowHeight); i < this->height(); i += static_cast<int>(rowHeight))
    //for (unsigned int counter = 0; counter < static_cast<GraphicScaleDialog *>(this->parent())->data->outputSettings.flowQuantity; counter++)
        painter->drawLine(0, i, this->width(), i);

    pen->setColor(Qt::lightGray);
    painter->setPen(*pen);
    for(int i = 0; i < this->width(); i += 30)
      painter->drawLine(i, 0, i, this->height());

    delete pen;
}
```

Comment: Is your problem that scroll bars don't appear?

Comment: Yes, and I don't see grid scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Designer, in your `QScrollArea` uncheck `widgetResizable` property or use `QScrollArea::setWidgetResizable` to turn it off programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your `TimeDiagram` widget should override `sizeHint()`, so to tell layouts its preferred size. This is used by `QScrollArea` to determine the displayed widgets's size.

The base `QWidget`'s  implementation will use the minimum size, so this should work:

```
commonDiagramWidget->setMinimumSize(2000, static_cast<int>(data->outputSettings.flowQuantity * commonDiagramWidget->rowHeight));
resultsDiagramWidget->setMinimumSize(2000, 101);
```

See [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#size-hints-and-layouts) docs